# Run command on mouse click

Tags: sound, mouse

I want my left mouse click produce a sound (for desktop video recording). Therefore I want to execute "mpg321 /home/me/Desktop/mouseclick.mp3" command which plays a mouse click sound every time my left mouse button is pressed.

Could you please provide me a working bash script to catch left mouseclick and execute a command? Thanks

Comment: Check [this](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/106736/detect-if-mouse-button-is-pressed-then-invoke-a-script-or-command)

Comment: I already checked this post, and bin/sh script truly works, but i was not able to edit it to my likings, lack of programming knowledge and script's readibility is zero :/ therefore the initial question is whether someone could provide working script

Comment: @Maris I think I can help you with that.  I can edit that script, but I need to know your exact requirements. Right now your question is not very clear. Can you explain how the script should behave exactly ? Is it only when you're doing recording or always  ?